# Why does removing grid() make my program turn blank?

Tags: python, tkinter, screen

I'm using `.place()` in my tkinter program, so I wanted to remove references to `grid()`. So far my program works but for some reason there's a single `.grid()` line that makes my whole program turn blank if it's removed. This shouldn't happen, since I'm entirely using `.place()`. Here is that line:

```
    AllFrames.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
```

And here is my full code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Account Signup")
DarkBlue = "#2460A7"
LightBlue = "#B3C7D6"
root.geometry('350x230')

Menu = Frame()
loginPage = Frame()
registerPage = Frame()
for AllFrames in (Menu, loginPage, registerPage):
    AllFrames.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    AllFrames.configure(bg=LightBlue)

def show_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
show_frame(Menu)

# ============= Menu Page =========

menuTitle = Label(Menu, text="Menu", font=("Arial", 25), bg=LightBlue)
menuTitle.place(x=130, y=25)

loginButton1 = Button(Menu, width=25, text="Login", command=lambda: show_frame(loginPage))
loginButton1.place(x=85, y=85)

registerButton1 = Button(Menu, width=25, text="Register", command=lambda: show_frame(registerPage))
registerButton1.place(x=85, y=115)

# ======== Login Page ===========

loginUsernameL = Label(loginPage, text='Username').place(x=30, y=60)
loginUsernameE = Entry(loginPage).place(x=120, y=60)
loginPasswordL = Label(loginPage, text='Password').place(x=30, y=90)
loginPasswordE = Entry(loginPage).place(x=120, y=90)
backButton = Button(loginPage, text='Back', command=lambda: show_frame(Menu)).place(x=0, y=0)
loginButton = Button(loginPage, text='Login', width=20).place(x=100, y=150)

# ======== Register Page ===========


root.mainloop()
```

I've also noticed that changing anything in the parentheses causes the same result. For example, if I change `sticky='nsew'` to `sticky='n'` or `row=0` to `row=1` it will show a blank page.
How do I remove `.grid()` from my program without it turning blank?

Comment: Why do you think that the line `AllFrames.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')` can be removed?  It is required to show the frames, without that line the frames are invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `place()` manager does not reserve any space, unless you tell it directly.

The `grid(sticky='nsew')` makes the widget expand to fill the entire available space, in this case the containing widget. The widgets inside all use `place()` which will not take any space. When you change to `grid(sticky='n')` you place the zero size widget at the top of the containing widget.

But, for your current problem you can assign a size to the widgets:

```
AllFrames.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1) # w/h relative to size of master
```

I would recommend using the `grid()` geometry manager if you are going to make any more complicated layouts.

For more info have a look at [effbot on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190605100700/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm)